# Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

> Таким образом, задержки работы маршрутизирующего оборудования не
>   моделируются(,) и задержка передачи только что пришедшего пакета
>   следующему спутнику определяется только длиной очереди, скоростью
>   передачи межспутниковой линии и расстоянием до следующего спутника.

"Таким образом" относится и к первому и второму предложению. Можно ли подобно правилу с общим членом предложения не разделять запятой эти два предложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае вводное слово **является общим элементом**, хотя окончательное решение о постановке запятой следует принимать с учетом контекста.

В то же время приведенное предложение является распространенным, и отсутствие запятой **затрудняет понимание его структуры,**  да и прочитать его без паузы довольно сложно.

Поэтому предлагается **заменить союз И союзом А**, если сделать это позволяет контекст:

Таким образом, **задержки** работы маршрутизирующего оборудования **не моделируются**,  а **задержка** передачи только что пришедшего пакета следующему спутнику **определяется** только длиной очереди, скоростью передачи межспутниковой линии и расстоянием до следующего спутника.